# Custom links in Views

Tags: 7, views

For a Taxonomy Vocabulary on my Drupal 7 site, I have added several custom fields for each Taxonomy Term, and want to have two different ways of viewing the Term information: a summary and a detailed view.

I've created the two Views for summary and detailed (`myterm-summary/%` and `myterm-detail/%`). But now the question is how to create a link between them. I'd like a link on `myterm-summary/%` to link to `myterm-detail/%` as a "Read More..." link. Is there some View element I can add to the View to create a custom link, using the dynamic URL variable  in the process?

I know I can create a Rich Text block header or footer for the View, but can I refer to the URL variable in that text block somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution that you can use the Replacement Tokens to this effect. In order for the field you want to show up as a possible Replacement Token, it must be in the Fields list. So I did:

- Set Format to "Unformatted List"
- Set Show to "Fields"
- Add the "Term ID" field to Fields list.
- During creation (or edit it afterward), check the "Exclude from display" box.
- Create a new Footer element that's a "Global: Text Area" type.
- Check the "Use replacement tokens" box
- Insert `<a href="/myterm-detail/[tid]">More Info...</a>` in the box.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the "Global : Text Area" in the Header or Footer of the view to add the link. You can get the URL variable using a PHP snippet and use that to create a link. The following should work :

```
<?php  
$view = views_get_current_view();
print '<a href=\'/myterm-detail/'. $view->args[0] .'\'>Read More..</a>';
?>
```

Make sure you are using the PHP code text format.

Comment: I don't have a "PHP code" Text Format; is that an additional module?

Comment: Yes. Although it is included in the D7 core, you do have to enable it separately. Go to your modules page, under the core modules you will find a module called "PHP filter". Enable that.

Comment: Under no circumstances should you use php in a textarea or textfield in drupal! Forget the php filter completely! It will be removed from drupal 8 either.
What do you do, if an api change happens on an update, and your site is broken, because a function was removed?
Very happy to figure out, which textfield causes the problem..

Comment: Thanks @GaborSzanto. Additionally, if you have a PHP syntax error (which can be difficult to track if it's deeply down in some nested ifs e.g.) your site will go to a nice WSOD and you never find out again why. Have fun removing the culprit code then in the database tables using phpmyadmin or adminer. *Never* do that. PHP should not exist as database content in Drupal.